# Is it safe to save previous value of a column as a variable in update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Think of a simple update stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdateMyTable] (
    @Id int,
    @ModifiedOn datetime,
    @GeneratedOn datetime
)
AS
UPDATE
    [MyTable]
SET
    [ModifiedOn] = @ModifiedOn
WHERE
    [Id] = @Id AND [ModifiedOn] <= @GeneratedOn
```

Now, to return a result based on previous value of ModifiedOn, I changed it like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdateMyTable] (
    @Id int,
    @ModifiedOn datetime,
    @GeneratedOn datetime
)
AS
DECLARE @PreviousModifiedOn datetime
UPDATE
    [MyTable]
SET
    [ModifiedOn] = @ModifiedOn,
    @PreviousModifiedOn = [ModifiedOn]
WHERE
    [Id] = @Id AND [ModifiedOn] <= @GeneratedOn

IF @PreviousModifiedOn <= @GeneratedOn
    SELECT @ModifiedOn
ELSE
    SELECT -1
```

Is it safe to fill @PreviousModifiedOn variable, with previous value of ModifiedOn, in SET part? Or is it possible that ModifiedOn value changes before it is saved into variable?

---

**UPDATE**

Same query using `OUTPUT`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdateMyTable] (
    @Id int,
    @ModifiedOn datetime,
    @GeneratedOn datetime
)
AS
DECLARE @PreviousModifiedOn AS TABLE (ModifiedOn datetime)
UPDATE
    [MyTable]
SET
    [ModifiedOn] = @ModifiedOn
OUTPUT
    Deleted.[ModifiedOn] INTO @PreviousModifiedOn
WHERE
    [Id] = @Id AND [ModifiedOn] <= @GeneratedOn

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @PreviousModifiedOn WHERE [ModifiedOn] <= @GeneratedOn)
    SELECT @ModifiedOn
ELSE
    SELECT -1
```

It seems that `OUTPUT` is the correct way to solve the problem, but because of the *variable table*, I think it has more performance cost.

So my question is... Why using `OUTPUT` is better than my solution? Is there anything wrong with my solution? Which one is better in terms of performance and speed?

Comment: Where does `@PreviousModifiedOn` come from in the second example? You never declare it.

Comment: @ADyson Forgot to declare it... it must be declared before update... I edited my question :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is safe. Although variable assignment is a proprietary extension, the rest of the SET clause follows the SQL Standard here - all assignments are computed *as if* they occur in parallel. That is, all expressions on the right of assignments are computed based on pre-update values for all columns.

This is e.g. why `UPDATE Table SET A=B, B=A` will swap the contents of two columns, not set them both equal to whatever `B` was previously.

The one thing to be wary of here, for me, would be that the `UPDATE` may have performed *no* assignments (due to the `WHERE` clause) and so still be `NULL`, or may have performed *multiple* assignments; In the latter case, your variable will be set to one of the previous values but it is not guaranteed which *row*'s value it will have retained.

Comment: thank you Damien... multiple assignments will not happen because I'm checking Id in where clause and Id is unique. but for no assignments problem, I think I can fix it by checking @@ROWCOUNT and returning proper result if it is 0.

Comment: @RezaHN . . . The correct answer is to use the `OUTPUT` clause, not variables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... I Updated my question, I would be grateful if you could help please :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not required, since MS SQL Server 2005 you can use OUTPUT for this kind of scenarios.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdateMyTable] (
    @Id int,
    @ModifiedOn datetime,
    @GeneratedOn datetime
)
AS
DECLARE @PreviousModifiedOn datetime
--Declare a table variable for storing the info from Output
DECLARE @ModifiedOnTable AS TABLE
(
  ModifiedOn  DATETIME
)


UPDATE
    [MyTable]
SET
    [ModifiedOn] = @ModifiedOn,
    @PreviousModifiedOn = [ModifiedOn]
OUTPUT DELETED.ModifiedOn INTO @ModifiedOnTable
WHERE
    [Id] = @Id AND [ModifiedOn] <= @GeneratedOn

IF @PreviousModifiedOn <= @GeneratedOn
    SELECT ModifiedOn FROM @ModifiedOnTable
    ELSE SELECT -1
```

Comment: thank you Geovanny... but you have added a table and used @PreviousModifiedOn variable too... what was the problem of my solution? Does my solution work or not?

Comment: yeah, I added a table variable because I was not sure that your predicate only returns one row if you are sure that only return 1 row, you can replace the table variable, but I don't think it will be required for your query works without problem.

Comment: @GeovannyHernandez . . . The `OUTPUT` clause is the right way to solve this problem and this should be the accepted answer.